# Default Spring bean when profile is not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-profiles

I'm using Spring MVC controllers, and I'd like to make some extra request-mapped methods available during development. I can do this using Spring profiles:

```
@Controller
@Profile("!dev")
public class DefaultController {

}

@Controller
@Profile("dev")
public class DevController extends DefaultController {

}
```

But ideally, I'd rather not pollute the production classes' code with annotations referring to the 'dev' profile.

I think maybe it's possible using Primary annotation, but I can't get it to work. 
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076557/not-loading-a-spring-bean-when-a-certain-profile-is-set) seems to say that this should work:

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController {

}

@Controller
@Profile("dev")
@Primary
public class DevController extends DefaultController {

}
```

But when I do that, Spring tries to load both controllers when it starts up under the 'dev' profile, and fails with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0'
...
There is already 'defaultController' bean method
```

Is what I want to do possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your class `DevController` inherits from `DefaultController`. Keep classes separate. Don't extend `DevController` with `DefaultController` even if the contents are same.

Comment: Yes, that works. I've taken all of the code from `DefaultController`, and put it into an `AbstractController`. Both `DefaultController` and `DevController` now extend `AbstractController`. It's still not very clean though. Maybe I'll just copy and paste the code from `DefaultController` into `DevController`, or just stick with my original `@Profile("!dev")`.